# How to create a link inside a cell using EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I am trying to figure out how to write a Hyperlink inside a cell using EPPlus instead of the cell containing the link text. I need it to be recognized as a link and be clickable.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can't you use the **=HYPERLINK()** formula ?

Comment: have you tried **worksheet.Cells[i,j].Hyperlink** = new Uri(localfilepath)?

Comment: @TimWilliams that won't work because the data is loaded from a dataset.

Comment: @EmmanuelN I will try that. Seems like it may work. Will try it.

Comment: @IEnumerator - not sure I follow why HYPERLINK() couldn't work: either approach (using a formula or setting the hyperlink property) require the same information. Can you explain?

Comment: @TimWilliams i ran the code setting the value of the cell to =HYPERLINK('http://google.com') and it's still treated as text. it didn't produce an actual hyperlink.

Comment: @EmmanuelN go ahead and create an actual answer so i can mark this as complete. Your suggestion worked like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The below code worked fine with me.

```
string FileRootPath = "http://www.google.com";
_Worksheet.Cells[intCellNumber, 1].Formula = "HYPERLINK(\"" + FileRootPath + "\",\"" + DisplayText + "\")";
```

I hope this would help you.

Happy coding!!

Comment: Why not `_Worksheet.Cells[intCellNumber, 1].Formula = String.Format("HYPERLINK(\"{0}\", \"{1}\")", FileRootPath, DisplayText)` ?

Comment: Why not `String.Format(@"HYPERLINK(""{0}"", ""{1}"")", FileRootPath, DisplayText)` ;)

Comment: To me it seems not a universal solution because HYPERLINK function may not work for non-English versions of MS Excel. From this point of view the answer from Han is better.

Comment: Why not `$"HYPERLINK(\"{FileRootPath}\", \"{DisplayText\")"` (keeping the apparent tradition of adding a new way to format the output every few years since the OP in 2011).

Comment: Why not `String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, @"HYPERLINK(""{0}""; ""{1}"")", FileRootPath, DisplayText)` (Also: Mind the semicolon, as mine is not an english Excel)

Comment: @bell I would also suggest adding:
cel.Style.Font.UnderLine = true;
cel.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.Blue);
for formatting

Answer (score 109):

This is the other way to do:

```
var cell = sheet.Cells["A1"];
cell.Hyperlink = new Uri("http://www.google.com");
cell.Value = "Click me!";
```

I have tested. It works fine.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhhhh much easier than `\"","\"\"??"`  +1 THANKS\!

Comment: Thanks for this! I have to set Value after Hyperlink because otherwise I see address in the cell, not the value.

Comment: I have got an exception like Cannot find the definition of Hyperlink for System._ComObject . I have added EPPlus reference and no compilation error is there. Even i am using .net version 4.0. Can anyone tell me the reason for this runtime exception ?

Comment: And... How to create a hyperlink to another cell inside the workbook? I don't want to use filename, because I sent the file over internet, the user could change it.

Comment: I have used this before and works fine while using url but when I tried to link a file from file system, this is not working and giving error like `Excel found unreadable content` while opening excel. So @bell's answer is perfect for every situation.

Comment: Han's version didn't work for me, the Bell's version with Formula = HYPERLINK worked like a charm, thanks Bell

Answer (score 25):

There's a few ways to go about it:

1. To use URI, then set a human readable name:

   var cell = sheet.Cells["A1"];
   cell.Hyperlink = new Uri("https://www.google.com");
   cell.Value = "Click me!";
2. To use ExcelHyperLink and set a human readable name using object initializer :

   var cell = sheet.Cells["A1"];
   cell.Hyperlink = new ExcelHyperLink("https://www.google.com") { Display = "Click me!" };
3. To use =Hyperlink() formula:

   var cell = sheet.Cells["A1"];
   cell.Formula = string.Format("HYPERLINK({0},{1})", "https://www.google.com", "Click me!");
   cell.Calculate();

Comment: Where I can reference ExcelHyperlink ?

Comment: @Muflix Add a reference to OfficeOpenXml

Comment: @Muflix The new class should be ExcelHyperLink not ExcelHyperlink.  If you add the reference to OfficeOpenXml and fix the casing on the class name it will work.

Comment: To make the resulting Hyperlink appear as such I also needed to set an appropriate style - http://stackoverflow.com/a/19492666/54026

Answer (score 4):

Based on provided answers and documentation I was able to create an extension method that also deals with proper hyperlink formatting. It creates a named style, if needed, and use that style for all subsequent hyperlinks:

```
public static void WriteHyperlink(this ExcelRange cell, string text, string url, bool excelHyperlink = false, bool underline = true)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
        return;

    // trying to reuse hyperlink style if defined
    var workBook = cell.Worksheet.Workbook;
    string actualStyleName = underline ? HyperLinkStyleName : HyperLinkNoUnderlineStyleName;

    var hyperlinkStyle = workBook.Styles.NamedStyles.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == actualStyleName);
    if (hyperlinkStyle == null)
    {
        var namedStyle = workBook.Styles.CreateNamedStyle(actualStyleName);  
        namedStyle.Style.Font.UnderLine = underline;
        namedStyle.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.Blue);
    }

    if (excelHyperlink)
        cell.Hyperlink = new ExcelHyperLink(url) { Display = text };
    else
    {
        cell.Hyperlink = new Uri(url);
        cell.Value = text;
        cell.StyleName = actualStyleName;
    }
}
```

Without the styling, the hyperlink will look just as regular text, if `cell.Hyperlink = new Uri(url);` is used without explicit styling (although the cursor will properly indicate that the text is actually a hyperlink text).

Comment: Alternatively this can be used too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19492666/603807

Answer (score 2):

I don't know EPPlus, but in VBA (and I guess C# would use the same principle) you would use the following code:

```
Sub Test()

    ' place value into cell
    ActiveSheet.[A1] = 13

    ' create link and set its range property
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add ActiveSheet.[A1], "http://www.google.at"

    ' use cell in a calculation
    ActiveSheet.[A2].Formula = "=A1+2"

End Sub
```

Hyperlinks are objects having a range property, so while your cell value can be changed by overtyping, the link will remain. Edit the cell by a long mouse click

Hope this helps - good luck MikeD

Comment: Thanks @MikeD. I am doing this server side using EPPlus. Emmanuel's answer above addressed my issue correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using EPPlus and want to create a link to another sheet within the same document, then this is the proper way to do this:

```
  var link = "Another Excel Sheet"; //Maximum length is 31 symbols
  using (var excel = new ExcelPackage())
  {
       var ws = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Test");
       ws.Cells[row, col].Hyperlink =
                new ExcelHyperLink((char)39 + link + (char)39 + "!A1", 
                "Name of another excel sheet could be more then 31 symbols");
  }
```

This is the proper way to create a link to another sheet within Excel document. Having using formula with `HYPERLINK` function, if a file is downloaded to the client, latest Excel version will raise security warnings.

Comment: For those who wonder, `(char)39` is the single quote character, so this would also work: `new ExcelHyperLink($"'{link}'!A1")`