# Epplus use Excel Styles like Hyperlink

Tags: styles, epplus

I am trying to style some cells, I'd like to use the standard "Hyperlink" Style, but I am unable to find it.

here is my best guess code, but the Workbook does not contain a style other than "standard"

```
      var hLinkStyle = (from s in dataSheet.Workbook.Styles.NamedStyles where s.Name == "Hyperlink" select s).FirstOrDefault();
      hyperlinkCell.StyleName = hLinkStyle.Name;
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try to create a named style and set it to the cell as follows:

```
// string link = "your link".
// worksheet is your worksheet reference.
var namedStyle = worksheet.Workbook.Styles.CreateNamedStyle("HyperLink");
namedStyle.Style.Font.UnderLine = true;
namedStyle.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.Blue);
cell.Hyperlink = new ExcelHyperLink(link);
cell.StyleName = namedStyle.Name;
cell.Value = link;
```

Please refer to [EPP example](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/Formatting-and-styling) for detail.

Comment: Just going to call it out for anyone else - only do this once for the workbook, don't attempt to do it per sheet because you will get an error.