# How to make url within the text clickable in EP Plus excel export

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I am generating excel sheet from the data using epplus

I have a cell in my excel which has text and within that text there are some urls also. Something like this text

"Bla bla bla bla bla http://www.google.com bla bla bla"

So in this above text I just want the url to be clickable in the excel sheet cell and rest all the text should be normal text

Is there a possibility to do that?

There are ways to make the whole cell a hyperlink and make it clickable but I do not want the whole cell as hyperlink but urls within the text clickable.

This thread shows the ways to make the whole cell clickable but I do not want that

[How to create a link inside a cell using EPPlus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7639180/how-to-create-a-link-inside-a-cell-using-epplus)

Comment: Excel does not support this in the usual way. Therefore, it is bad idea to do this - it can confuse the user if he will edit the document.

Comment: @Jackdaw - Got it. But is it possible to achieve it in any way?

Comment: @Jackdaw - When I try the excel online, it does allow this way